# How to set Textblock size to always fit the bound data?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock

I am working on a WPF GUI. I have many views and everyview has several TextBlocks, I am trying to get rid of an annoying design (I know red is annoying but that's not the case) so I will explain with couple sample Text Blocks and here is its XAML:

Sometimes there is data "Binding behind", sometimes it's a single word sometimes it's couple words and sometime there is not data at all. How can I set them beside each other whatever the data is?

```
<TextBlock x:Name="sessionNameTextBlock" Margin="0,0,1123,9.8" Text="{Binding CurrentSessionName}" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" FontSize="48" TouchUp="sessionNameTextBlock_TouchUp" MouseUp="sessionNameTextBlock_MouseUp" Height="57" Background="#FFE81616"/>
<Border x:Name="SessionEditorButton" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Margin="48,0,1027,9.8" MouseUp="SessionEditorButton_MouseUp" TouchUp="SessionEditorButton_TouchUp" Background="#FFF91515" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
   <Image x:Name="image" Margin="10,10,9.8,10.6" Source="/EZ3D;component/Resources/ez3d_edit.png"/>
</Border>
<TextBlock x:Name="sessionCommentsTextBlock" Margin="144,0,975,9.8" Text="{Binding CurrentSessionComments}" MouseUp="sessionCommentsTextBlock_MouseUp" TouchUp="sessionCommentsTextBlock_TouchUp" FontSize="18.667" Background="#FFF41515" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
```

The current state is this:
[image]

Or if I manually resize it:
[image]

**What I would like to have is this:**

**------------- Vision----------------**

In execution one the contents are 'S' and 'E', then execution two the contents are "Whatever... etc" and "Comments ... etc" So the TextBlock will resize depends on its content.
[image]

Comment: So you want the first and third `TextBlock`s to size to fit their contents?  What are those 3 elements contained in?

Comment: Correct. I want any TextBlock to be equal to its content. These three elements are in one row of a big grid

Comment: So then they are going to be constrained by the size of the grid right?  What happens when they are bigger (wider) than the grid?

Comment: It depends what size I set in the designer, anything out of the boundaries will simply disappear. Which is not cool. Should I put them in a StackPanel? but.. I don't think that's a solution, it should be simpler right?

Comment: If you are not doing a table-type format, I would use a `StackPanel` but that may not solve the problem.  Is the content variable, or does it stay the same once the window is loaded?

Comment: No it's variable, user can rename the session or/and edit comments

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106252/discussion-between-codinggorilla-and-firststep).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the following XAML behaves as you requested *for me*.

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb1" Text="Test" />
    <Border x:Name="SessionEditorButton" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0" Background="#FFF91515" Height="57" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Image x:Name="image" Margin="10,10,9.8,10.6" />
    </Border>
    <TextBlock x:Name="tb2" Text="Test 2"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Granted this works in a very contrived example, but what it comes down to is that the `TextBlock`s **will** automatically resize themselves *if* their container has the space to allow it.  In this case my `StackPanel` fills the window so there is plenty of room for the TB's to resize.  You may need to look at your container hierarchy to figure out which container is contraining your text blocks.

Comment: This did not work, as copy paste it still hides some of the text. I also added a StackPanel to some samples, that also didn't work

Comment: However it might be just my designer. So it's an answer